# How to show leading/trailing whitespace in a PostgreSQL column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, whitespace, psql

I can't see leading/trailing whitespace in the following following SQL statement executed with `psql`:

```
select name from my_table;
```

Is there a pragmatic way to see leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: Nothing built-in as far as I know. I typically enclose the values with some "marker" character: `select '>'||name||'<' from my_table`

Comment: instead of just name try '"' || name || '"'

Comment: For what it's worth, PgAdmin will give you the spaces

Comment: Turn off "aligned mode": `\a`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you post your comment (Turn off "aligned mode") as answer, I will up-vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind substituting all whitespace characters whether or not they are leading/trailing, something like the following will do it:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(txt, ' ', '_'),
                               E'\t', '\t'),
                       E'\r', '\r'),
               E'\n', '\n') AS txt
FROM test;
```

This is using an underscore to mark the spaces but of course you are free to choose your own. See [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2944e/2).

If you strictly only want to show up the leading/trailing ones it will get more complex - but if this is really desired, something may be possible using [`regex_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

Comment: Yes, this should work. In my case one `REPLACE(txt, ' ', '_')` would be enough.

Answer (score 13):

One of option is to use format() function.

With given query case: `select format( '"%s"', name ) from my_table;`

PoC:

```
SELECT  format( '"%s"', name )
FROM    ( VALUES ( ' a ' ), ( ' b ' ) ) v(name);

 format
--------
 " a "
 " b "
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to show up multiple spaces? Comparison of the two methods [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2944e/6).

Comment: @SteveChambers - not sure why you get such result. E.g. if I run `SELECT format( '"%s"', name ) FROM ( VALUES ( E'  \t  Hello there   \t  \r' ) ) v(name);` I get: `"         Hello there             \r"`. Removed `\n` as comments doesn't allow here multiline. But format() doesn't high-light them as your replace() solution – so depending how to want to capture whitespace can choose either one or another solution. Also question was leading/trailing whitespace, so in that context using format() can be one of option to solve it without needing to use multiple replace()-s :)

Comment: Apologies - I stand corrected - it works in rextester: http://rextester.com/FYNM80952 Not sure why but maybe something to do with how SQLFiddle presents the results?

Comment: No worries, probably SQLFiddle presenting does some "cleaning" of its own :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd append surrounding quotes:

```
select '"' || name || '"' from my_table;
```

Comment: This is up to now the shortes/simplest solution. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I noticed after I wrote it that someone had already suggested this in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off "aligned mode" in psql: `\a`

```
\a
select * from my_table;

id|col1|col2
12|foo|bar
```

Comment: Does not work for trailing spaces in the last column.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

select name from my_table
where name like '% '